# Jaccard in k-means clustering

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Cypher, how would you modify k-means to consider Jaccard distance Dj rather than Euclidean distance?

Where Jaccard Distance is defined as Dj=1-(|A∩B|)/(|A∪B|)

Comment: check this graphgist http://neo4j.com/graphgist/49a2b9874b37b4a2da4a/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to compute Jaccard distance with Cypher (from the [Recommendations Neoj Sandbox](http://neo4j.com/sandbox-v2)):

```
MATCH (m:Movie {title: "Inception"})-[:IN_GENRE]->(g:Genre)<-[:IN_GENRE]-(other:Movie)
WITH m, other, COUNT(g) AS intersection, COLLECT(g.name) AS i
MATCH (m)-[:IN_GENRE]->(mg:Genre)
WITH m,other, intersection,i, COLLECT(mg.name) AS s1
MATCH (other)-[:IN_GENRE]->(og:Genre)
WITH m,other,intersection,i, s1, COLLECT(og.name) AS s2
WITH m,other,intersection,s1,s2
WITH m,other,intersection,s1+filter(x IN s2 WHERE NOT x IN s1) AS union, s1, s2
RETURN m.title, other.title, s1,s2,((1.0*intersection)/SIZE(union)) AS jaccard ORDER BY jaccard DESC LIMIT 100
```

Once you compute that you can use it with your k-means algorithm. How are you running k-means? Also in Cypher?

Comment: Thanks so much! Yes, this will all eventually be a neo4j query.